# Msys gcc produces exe that results in "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: gcc, file-format, msys

On an Msys installation I use only occasionally, I could not produce a working executable with gcc. I upgraded the system with `pacman -Suy` but the error persists.

Here is a session transcript:

```
$ gcc -v array-indexing.c -o array-indexing.exe
gcc -v array-indexing.c -o array-indexing.exe
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-msys
Configured with: /c/_/S/gcc/src/gcc-10.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-msys --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --disable-multilib --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --disable-win32-registry --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-isl-version-check --enable-checking=release --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'array-indexing.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../lib/../include/w32api -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/../lib/../../include/w32api array-indexing.c -quiet -dumpbase array-indexing.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase array-indexing -version -o /tmp/ccHxGOyu.s
GNU C17 (GCC) version 10.2.0 (x86_64-pc-msys)
        compiled by GNU C version 10.2.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

warning: GMP header version 6.2.0 differs from library version 6.2.1.
warning: MPC header version 1.1.0 differs from library version 1.2.1.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/../lib/../../include/w32api"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../lib/../include/w32api
End of search list.
GNU C17 (GCC) version 10.2.0 (x86_64-pc-msys)
        compiled by GNU C version 10.2.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

warning: GMP header version 6.2.0 differs from library version 6.2.1.
warning: MPC header version 1.1.0 differs from library version 1.2.1.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 5dc831ba8ba50cc9f8b7e3207bc4f700
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'array-indexing.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/as.exe -v -o /tmp/ccyivrKf.o /tmp/ccHxGOyu.s
GNU assembler version 2.36.1 (x86_64-pc-msys) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.36.1
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'array-indexing.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/msys-lto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc7hM2x2.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsys-2.0 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id -m i386pep --wrap _Znwm --wrap _Znam --wrap _ZdlPv --wrap _ZdaPv --wrap _ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t -Bdynamic --dll-search-prefix=msys- --tsaware -o array-indexing.exe /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../lib/crt0.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../.. /tmp/ccyivrKf.o -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmsys-2.0 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../lib/default-manifest.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/crtend.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'array-indexing.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
$ file array-indexing.exe
file array-indexing.exe
array-indexing.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
$ ./array-indexing.exe
./array-indexing.exe
bash: ./array-indexing.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
$
```

I'm at a loss. To my admittedly non-expert eye, the output looks inconspicuous. In particular, the generated file is recognized as a Windows executable.

The only thing standing out are these two warnings:

```
warning: GMP header version 6.2.0 differs from library version 6.2.1.
warning: MPC header version 1.1.0 differs from library version 1.2.1.
```

Googling didn't produce much insight — there was a broken dwarf5 a year ago, but the transcript shows it's using dwarf2, and that was about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `--with-dwarf2` configure argument actually means dwarf 2 or later (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=59447)). So I do think that you have dwarf5 debug info, and you need a newer binutils version which [correctly uses them](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27268). Try stripping the debug info, then it will probably work.

Comment: @ssbssa That seems to be the reason, thanks. (Plus a silent failure to upgrade gcc etc., see my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably as ssbssa said in a  comment: The compiler produced dwarf5 output which the runtime could not handle. The executable ran when stripped of debug information.

The issue was compounded because for some reason even repeated `pacman -Suy` didn't upgrade gcc or the binutils (I hadn't checked and thought that 10.2.0 was the latest available msys gcc version). Even though that command didn't output any error messages, it didn't upgrade non-core packages. It is possible that some msys processes still lingered and prevented upgrading non-core package upgrades, even though the installation closed the mintty console I was upgrading from.

For some reason the upgrades worked when I followed the advice on [this page](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-installation/). I issued the command `pacman --needed -S bash pacman pacman-mirrors msys2-runtime`, followed by `pacman -Suu`, and a lot of package upgrades were performed successfully, resulting in a working toolchain.